# Expected sum of the draws by Mr. B?

Tags: random-variables

Ms. A selects a number **X** randomly from the uniform distri-
bution on **[0,1]**. Then Mr. B repeatedly, and independently, draws numbers
**Y1**,**Y2** ,.... from the uniform distribution on **[0,1]**, until he gets a number larger than **X/2**, then stops. What is the expected sum of the draws by Mr. B, given **X**=**x**? This is a modification of a question I posted earlier, where you had to find the expected number of draws by Mr.B required for one success.

Please give me a hint or something for this one, I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the index of the first time the event $\{Y_k\geq X/2\}$ occurs.

That is that $N:(Y_N> X/2)\wedge \bigwedge\limits_{k=1}^{N-1} (Y_k\leq X/2)$

So the series, $\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k$ is the sum of $(N-1)$ values of $Y_\star$ known to at most $X/2$ and $Y_N$, the first such value that is greater.

Thus since Expectation is Linear :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E\Big(\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k\mid X=x\Big) ~=~ &  \big(\mathsf E(N\mid X=x)-1\big)~\mathsf E(Y_\star\mid Y_\star\leq x/2)+\mathsf E(Y_\star\mid Y_\star\gt x/2) \end{align}$$

---

Now because the $\{Y_\star\}$ values are iid uniform $[0;1]$ we know $\mathsf E(Y_\star\mid Y_\star\leq x/2) ~=~ \boxed ?$ and $\mathsf E(Y_\star\mid Y_\star > x/2) = \boxed ?$.

Also the conditional distribution of $N$ given $X$ is *(what?)*, which means that: $$\mathsf E(N\mid X=x) ~=~ \boxed?$$